# $id=1 or $id=2 or $id=3

Tags: php, mysql, css

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT number FROM domains WHERE domains_id=1");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$domain = $row['number'];

if($domain = 0){
<li class="icon"><a href="">Rule 1</a></li>
<li class="icon"><a href="">Rule 2</a></li>
}

if($domain = 1){
<li class="icon"><a href="" class="yes">Rule 1</a></li>
<li class="icon"><a href="">Rule 2</a></li>                                              
}

if($domain = 2){
<li class="icon"><a href="">Rule 1</a></li>
<li class="icon"><a href="" class="yes">Rule 2</a></li>
}
```

I have the above code but it does not seem to work.

When result is

- 0 - No rules are red
- 1 - Rule 1 is red
- 2 - Rule 2 is red

Please can you advise how I would get this to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It appears you are not comparing the values appropiately, try == instead of =

Comment: You should use if,else if statements if the conditions are mutually exclusive, in addition to using an equivalence operator instead of an assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if($domain == 0){
<li class="icon"><a href="">Rule 1</a></li>
<li class="icon"><a href="">Rule 2</a></li>
}

if($domain == 1){
<li class="icon"><a href="" class="yes">Rule 1</a></li>
<li class="icon"><a href="">Rule 2</a></li>                                              
}

if($domain == 2){
<li class="icon"><a href="">Rule 1</a></li>
<li class="icon"><a href="" class="yes">Rule 2</a></li>
}
```

You're using a single `=` when you need a double `==`

Comment: I would even say he needs a triple `===`. Why? Because if you can have strict comparison, you should have it. Just replace "`$domain = $row['number'];`" with "`$domain = (int)$row['number'];`" to make sure types match.

Comment: omg I feel so stupid! why the hell did I not remember that :( works fine now with just the ==.

Is this the best way of achieving what I am looking to do? Or is there another option?

Comment: Glad to hear it works. This is the way you should do it. You could also use an [elseif](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php).

Comment: @user1856414: Yes, the better option is to make sure you work on integers and compare strictly. Otherwise when the domain is not set and you have notices turned off, this solution will make you think the `$domain` was `0` (because `null == 0` is true, but `null === 0` is false, and without notices getting undefined index will get you `null`).

Comment: @Tadeck so what would you suggest I do/change?

Comment: @Sean: Did you forget to escape the HTML? [Others](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14162172/548696) [did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14162158/548696) [not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14162157/548696).

Comment: @user1856414: See my answer for details. Namely: using strict comparisons, plus - what I did not mention in the answer - turning on all the errors and notices (so you get information about places with issues in your code).

Comment: @Tadeck I have very basic knowledge and do not have a clue what strict comparisons are, do you have a link I could check out?

Comment: @user1856414: Ok, short introduction. `===` is strict comparison, `==` is loose comparison. First means "is identical", the second means "is equal". You can see them both here: [PHP: Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). To see how they behave in more detail, you have this resource: [PHP: Comparison Tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). Types are different subject, but type casting is here: [PHP: Type Casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting). Hope this will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the `=` in place of the `==`, you are also in violation of DRY. Try this instead:

```
echo '<li class="icon"><a href=""'.($domain==1 ? ' class="yes"' : '').'>Rule 1</a></li>';
echo '<li class="icon"><a href=""'.($domain==2 ? ' class="yes"' : '').'>Rule 2</a></li>';
```

Comment: ok, but how would you change this code if say you had a second class rule you wanted in the link?

Comment: `echo '<li class="icon"><a href="" class="myclass'.($domain==1?' yes':'').'">Rule 1</a></li>`

Answer (score 1):

You are using assignments instead of comparisons, but you should rather use strict comparisons (`===`) wherever possible:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT number FROM domains WHERE domains_id=1");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$domain = (int)$row['number']; // cast the result

if($domain === 0){?>
<li class="icon"><a href="">Rule 1</a></li>
<li class="icon"><a href="">Rule 2</a></li>
<?php}

if($domain === 1){?>
<li class="icon"><a href="" class="yes">Rule 1</a></li>
<li class="icon"><a href="">Rule 2</a></li>
<?php}

if($domain === 2){?>
<li class="icon"><a href="">Rule 1</a></li>
<li class="icon"><a href="" class="yes">Rule 2</a></li>
<?php}
```

In general I modified 3 things in your code:

- used comparison (`===`) instead of assignment (`=`),
- casted database result to integer (`(int)$row['number']`) for clean data,
- put HTML outside the PHP code,

**EDIT**: Just noticed another issue, noticed previously by others. You have 3 independent conditions checking the same data. Instead of these 3 condition statements you could use single statement consisting of one `if` end two `elseif`s.

Comment: I wonder if the down voters can actualy justify the down votes ;)

Comment: Your answer is flawless.

Comment: I wouldn't waste your time answering these trivial questions.

Comment: @DavidCaunt: I do not treat it as waste, it is just a break from more complex concepts. Call it "brain break" (break for the brain) ;)

Comment: @DavidCaunt it may be trivial to some people, but others have only just started out and need a little helping hand

Answer (score 0):

You're using an incorrect comparison operator. `=` does assignment, not comparison. You should be using `==`.

Also, you're not switching out of PHP, in order to output HTTP.

Try this:

```
<?php 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT number FROM domains WHERE domains_id=1");

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    $domain = $row['number'];
?>
<li class="icon"><a href="" class="<?php echo ($domain == 1)?"yes":""; ?>">Rule 1</a></li>
<li class="icon"><a href="" class="<?php echo ($domain == 2)?"yes":""; ?>">Rule 2</a></li>
```

Comment: Curious as to why the downvote... would love to improve this answer if there's a problem.

Comment: You nailed it. Best answer.

Comment: Your answer is correct, I wonder about downvotes also. Seems like someone is not really thinking on the answer, obviously cannot justify it (thus no comment following the downvote).